# What is a "complimentary license" for a software product?

Tags: licensing, terminology

I don't really understand the term.

I got a survey about either getting gift card or a complimentary license for a SDK control set.

But I really wonder what's complimentary license means?

I tried to search in their official site but didn't say anything about it...

Is it last for the life and I can use the controls in all my personal software and publish it?

Comment: Without any context, we can't tell you.

Comment: Best guess: you don't have to pay for it.  See definition 2 here: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/complimentary

Comment: @birryree what context? I thought complimentary license is a type of license that same for every company? No? I found couples company have form for request complimentary license too, but they didn't say what it is....

Comment: Yeah, but complimentary, while meaning free, doesn't specify anything else about it.

Comment: @birryree But that's what it said in the email :/ "select your choice of either a $10 Amazon Gift Card or a complimentary license for Telerik’s brand new Rad Controls for Windows 8".  So I have no idea what is the limitation :(

Comment: You can always ask them, or pick the option. The gift card is worth  $10 and the license is $100 if you were to buy one. Unfortunately we don't know what this offer of yours is, but I assume it's non-restricted or might have stipulations on it like not allowing commercial software to use it.

Comment: @birryree As a man & developer I picked the license anyway :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Complimentary" means free of charge, i.e. for free. Whether that means "free for X days", or "free for this version but not for any updates", or "here's a free product key that you can use just like a key bought for money" isn't said. In general, companies only give away things for free if they think they will somehow get a net profit from it. Most normal products are given away for free in the hope that the user will like it and buy more; with SDKs, the marketshare among programmers is often quite valuable to the vendor, so it might actually be a completely free, unrestricted one. But it's impossible to tell just from that phrase alone.

Comment: I guess this is the most accurate answer.  I wish they have a definition that tells me what's a Complimentary Lincense means...

Comment: It's like a complimentary suite when you gamble big at a Las Vegas casino. They're giving you something for free in the hopes that they'll get your future business or even better word of mouth references.

Comment: But like a complimentary breakfast, you usually get these "free" things by paying for something else.

Answer (score 1):

In short, that means free, aka without any charge like freeware or shareware.

Here is a reference information that states it in [**Wikipedia**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gratis).

> Many companies would often provide complementary goods and services
>   free of charge (i.e., on a complimentary basis). For example,
>   coffeehouses often provide Internet access free of charge to attract
>   more customers. Hotels often provide free shuttle services.
>   Restaurants often provide valet parking service free of charge.